# EventListener for a fresh app startup after being fully shut down

Tags: javascript, event-handling, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

What are the Ti.App.addEventListener for when a app start up from being totally shut down(iPhone: Double click on home button and removed from apps running in background mode). I need a listener for this new/fresh start up of The app. ‘resume’ don’t work in this case. Hope someone knows.

I ask for a eventListener that detects that the app has been shut down from running in background mode ala:

> Ti.App.addEventListener('resume', function(e)

all do 'resume' is not the right one in this case. Resume and pause don´t do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply fire your app start up function directly from app.js. This will only get evaluated during app start and not during app resume.